# nginx user public home without ~

Tags: nginx

Hi if I want to set user home for `public_html` as `http://mysite/user1/`
which there is no `~` before the `user1`

If visit `http://mysite/` it will go to `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`

I set config as below:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_Server;

    # Home directories
    location ~ ^/(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
      alias /home/$1/public_html$2;
    }
    location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
```

When I visit `http://mysite/user1/`, it works as I expect.

But now `http://mysite/` become `404`.
I am not very familiar with the regex and rule search sequence
How to make user home and the root both work?

Comment: Okay i will help you but my question is. If you access `http://mysite/` you want to access `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html` then what you want to access in case of hitting `http://mysite/user1/` ?

Comment: `http://mysite/user1/` will be `/home/user1/public_html/index.html` and `http://mysite/` will be `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally the URI `/` maps to the URI `/index.html` which also matches your regular expression. Assuming that the only subdirectories on your server are *users*, you could make the second `/` mandatory in the regular expression.

```
location ~ ^/(.+?)/(.*)?$ {
    alias /home/$1/public_html/$2;
}
```

Alternatively, make the `/index.html` URI explicit (by moving the `root` statement and adding an empty `location` block):

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
...
location = /index.html {}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.